# Best way to symbolically express this statement?

Tags: notation

1. Let $a$ and $b$ be parameters.

How can we say formally that if $d_{ij}\in [a,b]$, then $c_{ij}=f(d_{ij})$ and if $d_{ij}\notin [a,b]$, then $c_{ij}=0$?

2. I want to define $M_{i}$ as the combination of $j$ indexes while $d_{ij}< b$. Is the following notation correct?

$$M_{i}=\{j \in J :d_{ij}< b\}$$

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "formal". I would not be against simply

$$c_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
0, & d_{i,j} \not \in [a,b] \\
f(d_{i,j}), & d_{i,j} \in [a,b] \end{cases}$$

or, if one wants to use the language of characteristic functions,

$$\mathbf{1}_A(x) := \begin{cases}
1, & x \in A \\
0, & x \not \in A \end{cases}$$

then you could say

$$c_{i,j} = f(d_{i,j}) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(d_{i,j})$$

These are ultimately just the same thing; I wouldn't overcomplicate it unless you have a particular need in mind.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "combination"? If you're meaning a set then you should be using curly braces for set-builder notation.

Comment: Yes, I meant the curly notation. Thanks for the heads up! I am editing now. After editing, do you think it is correct now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use an [indicator function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), (also known as a [characteristic function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicFunction.html)). Then, we would notate this as

$$c_{ij} = \chi_{[a,b]}(d_{ij}) f(d_{ij})$$

(Edit: I agree with PrincessEev that for most uses a definition by cases would tend to be more readable.)

2. Yes, that notation is perfect. You have defined $M_i$ as the set of all $j$ in $J$ such that $d_{ij}$ is less than $b$.